# Why Pouchdb error has no view named when it is in the _design doc?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pouchdb

I have set a view in Pouchdb. And queried against it and I get an error that the view named "personnel" can not be found. When I look up the view doc I find the "_design/personnel" doc with a view named "personnel".  I have scoured the Googles and the Pouchdb docs and have not found a solution. Does anyone have an idea why this is not working?

```
var ddoc = {
  _id: '_design/personnel',
  views: {
    personnel: {
      map: function (doc) {
        if (doc.PrimeWorkOrderNum) {
          emit(doc.PrimeWorkOrderNum, {name: doc.EmployeeName, empId: doc.EmployeeID});
        }
      }.toString()
    }
  }
}

pouch.put(ddoc).then(function () {
  // success!
}).catch(function (err) {
  // some error (maybe a 409, because it already exists?)
});
```

Then I tried to run a query against the view.

```
this.findPersonnelByJobId = function(jobId){
      console.log(jobId);
      return db.query('personnel', {
        key: jobId,
        include_docs: true
      });
```

When I call findPersonnelByJobId() I get the error.

```
NotFoundError {status: 404, name: "not_found", message: "ddoc _design/personnel has no view named 
personnel", error: true, stack: "not_found: ddoc _design/personnel has no view name…    at http://127.0.0.1:9000/dist/app.js:66114:17"}
error: true
message: "ddoc _design/personnel has no view named personnel"
name: "not_found"
status: 404
stack: "not_found: ddoc _design/personnel has no view named personnel↵    at http://127.0.0.1:9000/dist/app.js:66114:17"
__proto__: Error
```

when I look up the view doc I find:

```
{_id: "_design/personnel", views: {…}}
views:
personnel:
map: "function (doc) {
↵            if (doc.PrimeWorkOrderNum)
```

The view was inserted by this object:

```
var ddoc = {
  _id: '_design/personnel',
  views: {
    personnel: {
      map: function (doc) {
        if (doc.PrimeWorkOrderNum) {
          emit(doc.PrimeWorkOrderNum, {name: doc.EmployeeName, empId: doc.EmployeeID});
        }
      }.toString()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The view doc as given is malformed in a big way - show the entire document.  A 409 response on a PUT means the document already exists.

Comment: thanks, Add the object view above

Comment: Did you figure out the issue?

Comment: no, not yet, got distracted with other projects and have not revisited.